# jenkins pipeline string compare

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to compare a variable with a constant String, instead of a Boolean. I am getting a `null`.
I tried using `.trim()` on the String variable and the constant String as well, but it didn't help.

```
def host = sshCommand remote: remote, command: "hostname"
echo "${host}" // this is printing the value
```

When I compare the returned value with a constant string, it is returning a `null`.

eg:

```
if (host == "host.domain.com")
```

OR

```
if ("${host} == "host.domain.com")
```

OR

```
if ("${host}.equalsIgnorecase("host.domain.com") == "true" )
```

None of the above attempts worked. Is there any possibility to do the comparison in a pipeline?

Comment: One could print the strings in bytes to compare what's different, `println "${host.getBytes()}"` and `println "${'host.domain.com'.getBytes()}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your three attempts:

```
if (host == "host.domain.com")
```

This is correct and should work. We would need to see more information in the question for why it is not working, including the surrounding code and helpful debug output.

```
if ("${host} == "host.domain.com")
```

This is missing a closing interpolation quote. After adding it like the below, then it should work correctly, and implicitly recast your variable to a String if necessary.

```
if ("${host}" == "host.domain.com")
```

For attempt three:

```
if ("${host}.equalsIgnorecase("host.domain.com") == "true")
```

This is comparing a Boolean on the LHS with a String on the RHS. This `==` operator will always resolve to `false`. You can fix this by comparing to a Boolean on the RHS. Also, there are missing interpolation quotes for the `host` variable to recast to String. You can fix this with either:

```
if (host.equalsIgnorecase("host.domain.com") == true)
```

or:

```
if ("${host}".equalsIgnorecase("host.domain.com") == true)
```

Comment: if i use == its working in a new pipeline, not sure what was the issue with old pipeline.
Also, if i use equals or equalsIgnoreCase its failing, are these string functions are supported in jenkins pipeline? or do i need to have any plugin for equals/equalsIgnoreCase/replaceAll functions to work?